# Magento2: How to override customer model file?

Tags: magento2, model, override-model

I want to override AccountManagement.php in `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement.php` directory.

My di.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Overwrite\AccountManagement" />
</config>
```

I am getting below error:-
[image]
My AccountManagement.php file:-

```
    <?php 
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Overwrite;   

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\View as CustomerViewHelper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share as ConfigShare;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer as CustomerModel;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\CredentialsValidator;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Validator;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Validator\Attribute\Backend;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory as ObjectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface as Encryptor;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\Helper\Security;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\ExpiredException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InputMismatchException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InvalidTransitionException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\UserLockedException;
use Magento\Framework\Intl\DateTimeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Math\Random;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils as StringHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as PsrLogger;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;

class AccountManagement implements AccountManagementInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Random $mathRandom,
        Validator $validator,
        ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory $validationResultsDataFactory,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService,
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        PsrLogger $logger,
        Encryptor $encryptor,
        ConfigShare $configShare,
        StringHelper $stringHelper,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor,
        Registry $registry,
        CustomerViewHelper $customerViewHelper,
        DateTime $dateTime,
        CustomerModel $customerModel,
        ObjectFactory $objectFactory,
        ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        CredentialsValidator $credentialsValidator = null,
        DateTimeFactory $dateTimeFactory = null,
        AccountConfirmation $accountConfirmation = null,
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager = null,
        SaveHandlerInterface $saveHandler = null,
        CollectionFactory $visitorCollectionFactory = null,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder = null
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->mathRandom = $mathRandom;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->validationResultsDataFactory = $validationResultsDataFactory;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->customerMetadataService = $customerMetadataService;
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
        $this->configShare = $configShare;
        $this->stringHelper = $stringHelper;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->customerViewHelper = $customerViewHelper;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->customerModel = $customerModel;
        $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
        $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter = $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
        $this->credentialsValidator =
            $credentialsValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CredentialsValidator::class);
        $this->dateTimeFactory = $dateTimeFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(DateTimeFactory::class);
        $this->accountConfirmation = $accountConfirmation ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(AccountConfirmation::class);
        $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SessionManagerInterface::class);
        $this->saveHandler = $saveHandler
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SaveHandlerInterface::class);
        $this->visitorCollectionFactory = $visitorCollectionFactory
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CollectionFactory::class);
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
    }


    /**
     * Change customer password
     *
     * @param CustomerInterface $customer
     * @param string $currentPassword
     * @param string $newPassword
     * @return bool true on success
     * @throws InputException
     * @throws InvalidEmailOrPasswordException
     * @throws UserLockedException
     */
    public function changePasswordForCustomer($customer, $currentPassword, $newPassword)
    {
        try {
            $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customer->getId(), $currentPassword);
        } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
           $this->sessionManager->setMyValue('1');                
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('The password doesn\'t match this account.'));
        }
        custom code here....
        $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
        $this->credentialsValidator->checkPasswordDifferentFromEmail($customerEmail, $newPassword);
        $customerSecure = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId());
        $customerSecure->setRpToken(null);
        $customerSecure->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
        $this->checkPasswordStrength($newPassword);
        $customerSecure->setPasswordHash($this->createPasswordHash($newPassword));
        $this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

        return true;
    }   
}
```

**Edit:**
After added all function and dependencies, I am able to override the model, but after override I want to set some value in session in changePasswordForCustomer function, it give me below error:-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface\Proxy::setMyValue()
```

Any help would be much appricated

Comment: show your contractor

Comment: @SohelRana I have updated my question, please review and suggest me the solution if any

Comment: I am still waiting for solution

Answer (score 1):

It is because Customer Factory in your construct try to find the file in your current model path instead of the original model path. In your "use" list at the top of the class add this :

use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;

Or you could also change the construct in your class, by changing this :

```
public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
```

for this

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
```