# Magento2: How to customize the Billing address form?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, form-validation, billing-address

Currently there is no validation class available in phone number field.

[image]

I want to add "validate-digits" class, but I am not able to find the related file, Please help me how to do this changes so phone number only accept number only.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create di.xml file in  Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml & put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="validate_telephone_checkout_layoutprocessor" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

Now, create LayoutProcessor.php in Vendor\Module\Plugin\LayoutProcessor & put below code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class LayoutProcessor
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
        )) {

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
            ['telephone']['validation'] = ['required-entry' => true, "validate-number"=>true, "min_text_length" =>10, "max_text_length" =>  10 ];
        }

         /* config: checkout/options/display_billing_address_on = payment_method */
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
        )) {
            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                     ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {
                    /* telephone */
                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['telephone']['validation'] = ['required-entry' => true,"validate-number"=>true, "min_text_length" =>10, "max_text_length" =>  10 ];
            }
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are rock, it working as expected

Comment: accept answer if answer is worked

Comment: I already accepted

Comment: Can you please look into  [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297473/magento2-how-to-override-customer-model-file) as I am not able to override model